# Get sequential number of related object

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was completely not sure how to compose title so sorry for not very descriptive topic.

I have two tables, `A` and `B`. `B.foo` is a FK to `A.id`. Table `B` also has an `id` column.

Is there a way to get result like:

```
|a_id|b_id|b_foo_number
|1   |1   |1
|1   |2   |2
|1   |56  |3
|2   |3   |1
|2   |12  |2
|2   |57  |3
```

From table `B` looking like this:

```
|id|foo
|1 |1
|2 |1
|56|1
|3 |2
|12|2
|57|2
```

Right now I'm completely clueless, how could I do it.

Comment: What does table A have to do with the question?

Comment: You probably need a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)`...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated an example - if there is multiple values in table A I'd like to get counter from 1 to N for each 'slice'(by foo) of table B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT foo AS a_id, id AS b_id, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS b_foo_number
FROM B
WHERE foo = 1
```

If you want to get sequential numbers per `foo` slices, then use `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT foo AS a_id, id AS b_id, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foo ORDER BY id) AS b_foo_number
FROM B
ORDER BY foo
```

Answer (score 2):

The following produces the output you specify:

```
select 1 as a_id, b_id,
       row_number() over (partition by foo order by a_id) as b_foo_number
from b;
```

However, it is not clear that this is what you really need.  You need to better specify your question.

Comment: i'd order the row_number by `b_id`